# Include the content of a jsp in a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, include

I have this servlet:

```
public class SaveImage extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            ...

            // I want to include here the content of this jsp:
            // /WEB-INF/mybox.jsp
            // (also, with the full context of the servlet)

            ...
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a problem doing it (response already committed?), how can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/my.jsp").include(request, response);
```

But you should not a servlet for outputting html like that. Just use a jsp, with either `<jsp:include />` or `<%@ include file=".." %>`

Comment: Hi Bozho, are we able to use request.getRequestDispatcher().include() with parameter set (not attribute)? Something like when we are using <jsp:include /> we can set the parameter. Is it possible? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

THANKS ozho , YOU HAVE HELPED ME TO give final shape to 2 year old pending project. Thanks.
Actually to redirect the request of tomcat from sun web server 7 to application server, since the jsps are not shown in tomcat directly, technique is to use a passthrough in app.config and let the tomcat handle the requests.

```
            import java.io.IOException;

            import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
            import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

            /**
             * Servlet implementation class MY... Parvez Ahmad Hakim
             */
            public class MY extends HttpServlet {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                /**
                 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
                 */
                public MY() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

                /**
                 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 */
                protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    


                    String pageName =request.getParameter("req");       
                    if(pageName==null){ 
                        pageName="IC_LIC_Login.jsp";// default page
                    }
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(pageName).include(request, response);



                }

                /**
                 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 */

                protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
                    String pageName =request.getParameter("req");       

                    request.getRequestDispatcher(pageName).include(request, response);
                }


            }
```