# jsp ${pageContext.request.contextPath} dosent get requested

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Currently i have a .jsp project where my welcome page is a servlet

```
<welcome-file>frontpage</welcome-file>
```

The servlet sets gets two ressources, a header file containing the < nav> and a footer containing the < footer>

```
request.setAttribute("header1", sc.getResource("/includes/nav.jsp").toString());
request.setAttribute("footer", sc.getResource("/includes/footer.jsp").toString());
```

And forwards to the index.jsp page

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

My question is.
When i get the ressource (footer.jsp), how can i in the footer.jsp dynamically import / include images?

I tried the following

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/picture1.png" alt="picture1"/>
```

But the expression ${pageContext.request.contextPath} gets treated as a string instead of a command, and does not get the context path.

I suspect its because the content of the footer.jsp is fetched in this manner and their for the context path isint actually ever requested within the footer.jsp.

But how do i solve this?

Comment: kindly request to you accept the ans of @rembo it's working fine

Answer (score 3):

add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` in top of your JSP page, to enable expression language.

and to include a JSP page with other use `<jsp:include` like:

```
<jsp:include page="/includes/nav.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="/includes/footer.jsp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Rambo, everything is working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to include stuff. Use [jsp:include](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-include-action-tag/) action to include the header/footer. If for some reason you really want to do it in the servlet, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985235/include-the-content-of-a-jsp-in-a-servlet). As long as you just grab a resource like you do, you're  reading the file like any text, there is no JSP compilation/evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely read your posted links